# PHP can I leave a blank execution code for 'If"?

Tags: php

I am writing a cart system, for this cart action, if selected item already in the cart, I want the the function to add nothing, so I leave it blank. Is it proper practice to do so? Or is there any professional way to do?

```
<?PHP
...............

      // Is product already in cart? If so, add nothing.
      if(in_array($productName, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
    // do nothing...........so leave it blank?
      } else {
        // Product is not in cart, but we have other products in cart.
        // So just add to existing cart array.
        $_SESSION['cart_item'] = array_merge($_SESSION['cart_item'],$itemArray);
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: just add `!` in front of condition
`if(!in_array($productName, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {`
and remove else condition and put else condition code into if block

Comment: It's usually better to avoid blank conditions like this and as suggested, using ! (personally I prefer === false - but anyway).  One thing that is important is that if you do end up with blank conditions like this is to put a comment to say it's intentionally blank, this lets others know it's not a mistake but done for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can leave it blank but imho It's better this:

```
  if(!in_array($productName, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
    $_SESSION['cart_item'] = array_merge($_SESSION['cart_item'],$itemArray);
  }
```

You can add `!` to specifiy a `NOT` operation so you can delete else condition and you don't need to leave an `if` statement blank

Answer (score 2):

You can, but why not just switch the conditions?

```
<?PHP
...............

  // Is product not in cart? If so, add it.
  if(!in_array($productName, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
$_SESSION['cart_item'] = array_merge($_SESSION['cart_item'],$itemArray);
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have blank code block after `IF`, then simply use negation `!`.

```
if (!in_array($productName, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
```

Then code should be more easily to read by other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Because you identify the products in the cart by the keys of an array, instead of:

```
in_array($productName, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
```

you can simply check if:

```
array_key_exists($productName, $_SESSION["cart_item"])
```

It's the same verification but it runs much faster.

Even more, you don't even need to verify if the key exists. You can use the [union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) (`+`) that, for arrays, "adds" to the first array only the keys and their values from the second array that doesn't already exists in the first array.

All in all, the code that adds the selected product(s) to the cart can be as simple as:

```
$_SESSION['cart_item'] += $itemArray;
```